# Can't show CSS background image in Apache 2.2

Tags: css, apache

Here's a weird problem:
I configured my Apache httpd server just now. I wrote a simple test.php and it works correctly.
Then I wrote a css file which looks like:

```
.home div.sma{
     background:url('../images/carlos.png') 50% 0px no-repeat; 
}
```

The problem is:

The css file loads correctly and all other styles work fine. The only problem with it is that all images referenced in a CSS file using `background:url` won't work, but all images directly referenced in PHP file(`<img src="" />`) work well.

I've tried replace `../images/carlos.png` by `http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png`, the problem still exists.

Weird problem, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Could be cache problem?

Comment: @Mr_Green well, I've done nothing with cache... It never works correctly. My mate uses Mac and it's fine on his machine. But it won't work on two of my WIndows computers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK，problem solved. It turns out to be a problem with php.ini:

Certain class names are generated by PHP code with short_open_tags(`<? //code ?>`), but short_open_tag is Off by default in Windows.(It's On in Mac and Ubuntu). So, even the CSS file is loaded correctly, some selectors can't find corresponding class names because they haven't been generated.

By the way, I've also encountered that certain CSS files are categorized to `Images` when inspecting elements in Chrome, which brings trouble to debugging. To solve this, simply remove all `background:url(path)` statements within which `path` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The class reference on you test.php is good ?

In home element class, the div with the class name sma :

```
<div class="home">
<div class="sma></div>
</div>
```

You can put a border to see if the size of your div.sma is good...

Did you put some special security params in apache ?

Comment: I'm sure the class reference is good. In fact, others can run my projects in their environment correctly. I simply use the default settings, is there anything I should pay attention to？

Comment: Maybe a security rules in your htaccess file ?